# Visual Basic Text File

Tags: vb.net, listbox, text-files

I'm currently learning about Visual Basic text files but I came across a problem. I'm supposed to create a text file (Players) with data inside and I have to design a form with listbox to include the players’ names that are more than 30 years old.

This is my current code:

```
Dim q1 = From itm As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Players.txt")
Let Data=itm.Split(","c)
Let fname = Data(0)
Let age = Data(4)
Let newline = fname * " "& age
Where age > 30

For Each itm1 As String in q1
    ListBox1.Items.Add(itm1)
Next
```

My expected output should show the names of players that are over 30 years old. Thank you in advance to anyone that can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq. For example: assume you have a txt like that

```
Giuseppe, 30
Pippo, 13
Luca, 32
```

to extract only over 30 years old you can do...

```
Dim obj = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Players.txt").Split(vbCrLf).ToList()
Dim ret = (From a In obj Where a.Split(",")(1) > 30 Select a).ToList
```

The result is

```
Luca, 32
```

Comment: This answer is basically good but could be improved. Rather than calling `ReadAllText` and `Split`, call `File.ReadAllLines`. In either case, you get a `String` array, so why call `ToList`? If you really want to process the data further and discard some of it, `File.ReadLines` would be better: `Dim over30s = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(Function(line) CInt(line.Split(","c)) > 30).ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a class to define `Player`. I also made a class `Players` to hide the file processing from the consumer.

```vb
Public Class Player
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class

Public Class Players
    Private _list As New List(Of Player)()
    Public ReadOnly Property List As IEnumerable(Of Player)
        Get
            Return _list
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(path As String)
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
        For Each line In lines
            Dim split = line.Split(","c)
            If split.Count = 2 Then
                _list.Add(New Player() With {.Name = split(0), .Age = Integer.Parse(split(1))})
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

And use databinding to populate the ListBox

```vb
Dim ps = New Players("Players.txt")
Me.ListBox1.DataSource = ps.Items.Where(Function(p) p.Age >= 30).ToList()
Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

If you're not into the whole `Players` class and `Items` property, you can still use the `Player` class, and just do all the processing in your consuming code (it's basically the same thing, but the processing code is not encapsulated in the model).

```
Dim ps = New List(Of Player)()
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Players.txt")
For Each line In lines
    Dim split = line.Split(","c)
    If split.Count = 2 Then
        ps.Add(New Player() With {.Name = split(0), .Age = Integer.Parse(split(1))})
    End If
Next
Me.ListBox1.DataSource = ps.Where(Function(p) p.Age >= 30).ToList()
Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```